# Which book is useful to understand the use of article?

Tags: word-usage

I am always confused with using the articles "a/an/the" and countable/uncountable nouns. Could you suggest some books or workbooks for me to practice?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's asking for resources for learning English.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know any books but I could give you a brief explanation as a native English speaker.

## **a**

“**a**” is the indefinite article and is used when the noun does not begin with a vowel sound. Example: “**a** cat”, “There is **a** cat over there.”

## **an**

“**an**” is the same as **a** except that it's used when the noun begins with a vowel sound. Example: “**an** apple”, “**an** hour”.

## **the**

“**the**” is the definite article and is used when you already know exactly what you are talking about. Example: “**The** cat sat on the mat.”

## **Countable/Uncountable**

When a noun is countable, it can be counted without the use of separate units. Examples: cats, apples, books, litres (or liters if you learn American English), cups. You would say “**many**”. Example: “There are **many** cats.”, “There are **many** litres of water”.

When a noun is uncountable, it can't be counted. You can't say “1 water” or “2 waters”, you would say “1 litre of water” or “2 litres of water”. Examples: water, liquid, paper. You would say “**a lot of**”. Example: “There is **a lot of** water.”

Comment: Sometimes I feel confused with "the xx of the xxx" and "the xx of xxx" or just "xxx" .I can't understand when they use. (xxx and xx are nouns)